# Counting unique records in HIVE/SQL with many-to-many mapping based on a uniqueness criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, hive, logic

The problem description is given as follows:
A user may have multiple accounts and multiple phone numbers linked to that account.
A single account might be linked to one or more phone numbers.
A single phone number might be linked to one or more accounts.
No two users will have the same account. 
 
No two users will have the same mobile number.

We have to find the number of unique users from this information.

A sample dataset may be given as follows:

`| mob_num | acc_num |
+---------+---------+
| mob01   | acc02   |
| mob01   | acc01   |
| mob02   | acc02   |
| mob03   | acc01   |
| mob11   | acc11   |
| mob12   | acc11   |
| mob13   | acc11   |
| mob21   | acc21   |
| mob21   | acc22   |
| mob21   | acc23   |`


Sample output for this dataset is: 3

> In this case, we have 3 unique users.
>  For example, one unique user
>   can be figured out as follows 
>  1) mob01 is linked with acc01,
>   acc02 
>  2) mob02 is linked with acc02 
>  3) mob03 is linked with
>   acc01 
>  A user can have multiple acocunts and mobile numbers. If
>   mob01 is linked with acc01 and acc02. We can safely assume that this
>   particular user has mobile number mob01 and accounts acc01 and acc02.
>   However, acc02 is linked with mob02 as well. Therefore, we can
>   conclude that mob02 belongs to the same user. Same with mob03. Hence,
>   even though there is many-to-many mapping we are sure that
>   mob01,mob02,mob03 and acc01, acco2 belong to a single user. 
>  
>   Using similar logic, mob11, mob12 and mob13 are linked with acc11.
>   This particular user has three mobile numbers linked to a single
>   account.
>  Further, mob21 is linked with acc21,acc22,acc23. This
>   user has a single mobile number linked to three accounts.
>
> No two user can have the same account number or mobile number. In this
>   way, we can establish the uniqueness criteria for a user.

Now considering the data is a table in HIVE/RDBMS, how can we calculate the number of unique users? (IF it is possible to solve this using SQL queries)

Comment: Kindly provide more information regarding on what basis we have to calculate unique visitors.

Comment: @SurendranathaReddyChappidi Thanks for reading the problem statement. I have added more details. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Although it is clear how you want to determine unique users it is not clear what your result should look like.  Can you please provide the expected output for your sample data?

Comment: @tonypdmtr Added the expected output for the dataset. The output should be an integer.

Comment: Question looking like incomplete one..